# Can !Ref and !Sub be used interchangeably on any use case in aws cloudformation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Can !Ref and !Sub be used interchangeably in any use case? I need to substitute Parameter1 in environment variable LOCATION_UPDATE_SNS_TOPIC, So that this variable can be used programatically using python code inside the ec2. The Userdata property below for an ec2 instance is below.

```
UserData:
   Fn::Base64:
     !Sub |
     #!/bin/bash
     export LOCATION_UPDATE_SNS_TOPIC=!Sub Parameter1
```

or

```
UserData:
   Fn::Base64:
     !Sub |
     #!/bin/bash
     export LOCATION_UPDATE_SNS_TOPIC=!Ref Parameter1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you neither use `!Sub` nor `!Ref`. You already declared with the first `!Sub |` that the following contains parameter. The correct solution would be:

```
UserData:
   Fn::Base64:
     !Sub |
     #!/bin/bash
     export LOCATION_UPDATE_SNS_TOPIC=${Parameter1}
```

You can find some examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c31c28c59c11).